# Primefaces datatable is not populating with the list from backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a feedBackSearchList as follows,

List feedBackSearchList;

I'm trying to set this list to populate in datatable in my xhtml page.

```
setFeedBackSearchList(getFeedbackSearchService().getSearchResult(
                idemployee, idCliente, applicId, idEst, estId, idtecnologia));
```

I got the list from database, but it is not showing in xhtml page.

Please help me. The xhtml page is as follows,

```
<p:dataTable id="feedBackResultTab" var="feedBackResult" dynamic="true" value="#{feedbackSearchView.feedBackSearchList}" >
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Employee" />
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="output">
<h:outputText value="#{feedBackResult.employeename}" />
</f:facet>
    </p:column>
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Client" />
</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="output">
<h:outputText value="#{feedBackResult.desCliente}" />
</f:facet>
</p:column>
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Application" />
        </f:facet>
<f:facet name="output">
<h:outputText value="#{feedBackResult.applicationDesc}" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Estimation Methode" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{feedBackResult.desMethodEst}" />
                            </f:facet>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Technology" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{feedBackResult.destecnologia}" />
                            </f:facet>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Date" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{feedBackResult.fechaultimaactualizacion}" />
                            </f:facet>
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

Please help where I have done the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you access the objects like in an array instead of `feedBackResult.desMethodEst` just `feedBackResult[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You should not populate the list in the setter method. JSF will call the getter-method of your list if it builds the datatable. So you should either populate the list in the `getFeedBackSearchList` or (and even better): in a method `populateFeedbackSearchList` at bean construction time.

UPDATE:

Ok, you should change your columns like this:

```
<p:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Employee" />
  </f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{feedBackResult.employeename}" />
</p:column>
```

No facet is needed for the cell content, only for the header.

Comment: Yes, you said right. But, in this scenario, I have form with select boxes, based on selection I have to query the database, a list will be returned and I need to populate the datatable with the returned list.  Here I get list of type List<Object []> . How can I populate this list to the datatable.

Comment: @Narasimha Make sure that the set-method is called before you build the table. Add a breakpoint inside the get-method of your list and check if the list contains data at the time the datatable is built.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have done as you suggested.But List is not empty. the datatable is not able to show the data inside the list.I don't have a corresponding Model class for this backing bean. It will contact serveral model classes for property mapping. How can I access List<Object[]> in datatable.

Comment: Thanks for your response Matt. I removed facets for outputtext. But the result is same. Is there any work around for this problem.